# MySQL workbench not connecting my database. Backend is Python

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image]

Unable to get the tables in my database
MYSQL server 8.3 running in services
MYSQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: Mysql v8.3 is an experimental version and perhaps your current mysql workbench does not fully support it. Try upgrading mysql workbench to the latest version or downgrade your mysql to a supported version. If that does not help, you need to raise this query with mysql support, we cannot help you.

Comment: Thankyou for responding. Sure I will try to check with versions

Comment: Hey @Shadow I installed MySQL 8.0 and workbench is 8.0 CE and it's working fine. Thankyou once again.